# Sub Query in select clause with Squeryl

Tags: postgresql, scala, squeryl

I'm trying to replicate the following query usine Squeryl.

```
SELECT c.order_number,p.customer,p.base,( 
  SELECT sum(quantity) FROM "Stock" s where s.base = p.base  
) as stock 
FROM "Card" c, "Part" p WHERE c."partId" = p."idField";
```

I have the following code for  selecting the Cards and Parts but I cannot see a way to add a sumation into the select clause.

```
from(cards, parts)((c,p) => 
where(c.partId === p.id)    
select(c,p)
```

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Squeryl, you can use any [`Queryable`](http://squeryl.org/api/index.html#org.squeryl.Query) object in the from clause of your query. So, to create a subquery, something like the following should work for you:

```
def subQuery = from(stock)(s => groupBy(s.base) compute(sum(s.quantity)))

from(cards, parts, subquery)((c, p, sq) =>
  where(c.partId === p.idField and sq.key === p.base)
  select(c.orderNumber, p.customer, sq.measures))
```

Of course the field names may vary slightly, just guessing at the class definitions. If you want the whole object for `cards` and `parts` instead of the single fields from the original query - just change the select clause to: `select(c, p, sq.measures)`

Comment: Unfortunately it looks like its not possible to nest a subquery in a from clause that returns a primitive type: http://squeryl.org/limitations.html

Comment: Did what I posted not work for you? It doesn't return a primitive, but a `Query[GroupWithMeasures]` which should allow you to use as described.

Comment: I tried the above and got the following exception: "Sub query returns a primitive type or a Tuple of primitive type, and therefore is not useable as a subquery in a from or join clause, see 
http://squeryl.org/limitations.html" I'm not sure where `mp` came from - I assumed this was meant to be `sq`?

Comment: Which version of squeryl are you using - 0.95 or 0.96? I know I've used this in the past and I even can see reference to that type of query here: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!searchin/squeryl/subquery/squeryl/a5RXOCmQ0dw/f72e4f9-vDoJ However, I've been using 0.96 for a while and  it is possible that it is a feature that was only added to the 0.96 branch.

Comment: Hi jcern, I'm not sure why it didn't work first time but it does now! many thanks. I did change `mp` to `sq` which I think is a typo in your answer?

Comment: You are correct, I just updated the variable name. Glad it is working